# Topologically nilpotent operator acting an a topological group

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a compact (hausdorff) topological group. Suppose that there exists an operator $A$ which is a topologically nilpotent surjective morphism of this group. Is it true that $X$ must be a trivial group or there are counterexamples?

Comment: What does topologically nilpotent mean? I only see it applied to normed spaces, but here it seems you want it to be an operator on the group. Are we talking about a specific algebra here (L^1 with convolution)?

Comment: What is your definition of topologically nilpotent?  That $A^n(x)$ converges to the identity element for all $x$?

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes. In fact, I already know the answer to this question, I'll write it tomorrow if I won't be too lazy.